# Explode URL Query String Issue

Tags: php, arrays, url, explode

PHP newbie here.. I am trying to create a function where the user is redirected back to the previous page after adding an item to their cart. However, when they are redirected back with the code below it leaves a duplicate of the directory (ie. example.com/catalog/garden-tools/**garden-tools**

```
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    $url = explode('/', rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
    return $url[3];
}
```

A print_r reveals the following:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => thefarmshop [2] => catalog [3] => garden-tools [4] => gardening-glove )
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Thanks Jon. How would the implode function be implemented?

Comment: explode() turns a string into an array, implode turns an array into a string. explode('/','foo/bar/baz') returns array('foo','bar','baz'), implode('/',array('foo','bar','baz')) returns string 'foo/bar/baz'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the url is exploded, you get an array like:
`$url[ 0 ] = "http:"`
`$url[ 1 ] = "SOME_STRING"` and so on.
You need to check what is the index of the wanted string in your url array and return it. 
Like `return $url[ 2 ]` or whatever the index is.

**UPDATE**

```
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() {
    $url = explode('/', substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REQUEST'], 1));
    print_r( $url );
}
```

The `print_r( $array )` shows the `$array` structure including indices and values.

Comment: Ah yes. I get an `Array ( [0] => )`. What is this indicating?

Comment: That indicates an empty array. That means that your URL did not explode, probably because there is no "/" in there. What is the URL you are trying to explode?

Comment: The function runs when the product has been add to the cart. https://www.lospoblanos.com/thefarmshop/catalog/test-category/test-product

Comment: Yes, but what is the argument passed for the explosion? Just write `echo substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REQUEST']` before `print_r` and let me know.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `substr`? Try to print URL using `print( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_RUQUEST' ] );` only.

Comment: Michael, I have changed my function to get the url to explode. Please see the revised function above in my original question. I now am just getting a duplicate directory in the URL..

Comment: @IanMcAbee, well, I don't see any issue. It seems like the index you're looking for is 4: `$url[ 4 ] => gardening-glove`. Change your `$url[ 3 ]` to `$url[ 4 ]` and check the result.

Comment: Arg, `$url[ 4 ]` keeps me on the same page after adding the product to the cart..

Comment: Do you want to go up, or back?

Comment: Back so, for example it's "example.com/catalog/garden-tools/" and not "example.com/catalog/garden-tools/garden-tools/". Can I eliminate the extra directory?

Comment: The extra comes from the rest of your code. Where does the function return the url part to?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple test for this would look something like

```
$uri = '/test/uri/just/cause/';
print_r(explode('/', $uri));
```

Which yields the same thing you are seeing:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => test
    [2] => uri
    [3] => just
    [4] => cause
    [5] => 
)
```

The reason you are seeing the array element 0 as empty is due to the way explode works. It takes a character and sticks what's before it into an array element and whatever is after it in another array element.  For instance one/two would be split like array(one,two) since one is before the slash (/) and two is after (as expected)

However if there is nothing before or after, you will get an empty element as seen in the case above.

In your code you use rtrim() to trim the trailing slash, but you would get better results if you simply used trim() to trim the leading and trailing slashes.

```
$url = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
```

for your return, you might look for

```
return $uri[count($uri) - 2];
```

This would take you from example.com/catalog/garden-tools/gardening-glove and return garden-tools

UPDATE:
perhaps a simpler method for you would be as follows

```
$uri = rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/');
$uri = substr($uri, 0, strrpos($uri, '/'));
```

This will take a path such as example.com/catalog/garden-tools/gardening-glove and chop off the last bit leaving example.com/catalog/garden-tools

Comment: I'm using this and still getting example.com/catalog/garden-tools/garden-tools. I can't figure out how to remove the duplicate category in the url so it's just example.com/catalog/garden-tools

Comment: if you are getting example.com/catalog/garden-tools/garden-tools then how are you getting the first part of the URI? the return value of this function will simply be `garden-tools` so are you appending that to something?